# Can a Kipor KDE 7500STA power a water pump?

Tags: generator

I have a fully submerged water pump for my well which is 200 meters deep. The water pump is 3HP, and uses 15 Amps at 220V. Can this generator power the pump (I've provided a link below). In theory it should but I'd like to see if anybody has used it seeing as it's quite expensive.

Link to see info about the generator: http://www.kiporuk.co.uk/diesel-generator/kde-7500sta-diesel-generator-779-64-427.php

Edit: Somebody told me to use a startup capacitor. Would that help during the transition period?

Comment: Does it actually use 15 amps, or is that just the circuit breaker?  Is there any location on your property that is 10m+ higher altitude than your house?

Comment: No, the pump uses 15 Amps. And no, my house is the highest part of my property

Answer (score 1):

Your generator is specked at 6kva so it can supply 25 amps at 240v a standard 3 HP motor at 240 draws 12.2 amp  but even if your name plate is 15 amps it should be fine, the pump will pull the generator down a bit at start but once it is up to speed there is room to run other things. I know my well pump I just installed this year and it only draws ~60% of new name plate value once up to speed and that only takes a second or 2. I have monitored it with the system pressure just under 80psi when it shuts down and that’s when I measures the highest current again at ~60% of the fla value. Added:
I did not see your peak but did see the rating of 5.7 - 6.3k , even at the lower number you should be fine. Being a diesel here in the us costs way more but they usually last longer, it also has some nice features that less expensive generators don’t have.